# Suppress warning without modifying third party code

Tags: python, warnings, deprecation-warning

We use a third party open source tool and it generates a warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: The compiler package is deprecated and removed in Python 3.x.
```

How can I suppress this warning without modifying the third party code?

I know how to use `warnings.filter()` but I can't use it: I call `py.test` from the command line, thus no single source code line of my code gets executed before the warning gets created.

Creating a wrapper around the console script is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `usercustomize` or `sitecustomize` module that calls `warnings.filter()`. It'll be loaded as the interpreter starts.

See [The Customization Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-customization-modules):

> Python provides two hooks to let you customize it: `sitecustomize` and `usercustomize`. To see how it works, you need first to find the location of your user site-packages directory. Start Python and run this code:
>
> ```
> >>> import site
> >>> site.getusersitepackages()
> '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
> ```
>
> Now you can create a file named `usercustomize.py` in that directory and
>   put anything you want in it. It will affect every invocation of
>   Python, unless it is started with the `-s` option to disable the
>   automatic import.
>
> `sitecustomize` works in the same way, but is typically created by an administrator of the computer in the global site-packages directory, and is imported before `usercustomize`. See the documentation of the [`site`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) module for more details.

You can influence where Python looks with the [`PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE), so you can point Python to a per-project `usercustomize.py` file here, provided you take into account the path `lib/python/site-packages` is added to the base:

```
$ python -m site --user-site
/Users/someuser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ PYTHONUSERBASE=/foo/bar python -m site --user-site
/foo/bar/lib/python/site-packages
```

In the above example, with `PYTHONUSERBASE` set to `/foo/bar`, Python will load `/foo/bar/lib/python/site-packages/usercustomize.py` if it exists.

In a Python virtualenv a customised `site.py` file is used that is based on a `site.py` from before Python 2.6; this version omits the `getusersitepackages()` function. If the file `lib/pythonX.X/no-global-site-packages.txt` exists, the `usercustomize` module will *not* be imported. You'll have to use a `sitecustomize.py` file *in the virtual env `lib/python/site-packages` directory* instead.

Comment: My code runs in  a virtualenv, and I get: `site.getusersitepackages() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'`

Comment: @guettli: Updated to cover a virtualenv; an older `site.py` is used that omits that function.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, I found out that sitecustomize.py can be anywhere on the `PYTHONPATH` you are not forced to `lib/python/site-packages`.

Comment: Sure, it'll just try to import the module; but for a virtualenv `lib/python/site-packages` is guaranteed to be on your path. :-)

Comment: Hint: use usercustomize. On some linux distros a global sitecustomize exists, on some not. This can lead to confusing behaviour. No linux distro provides a usercustomize.